What can I do about a boss who refuses to reply to E-mails?
I work as a high school teacher and was recently assigned a new principal. Though its policy for us to check E-mail several times a day, two months into the school year, people noticed the principal wasn't replying to anything we were sending--it didn't matter if it was about some legal questions, fire code, safety issues, school policies, etc., everything went ignored. Thinking it was a server issue, some reached out to ask what's up. She wouldn't explain why, but told her close team she doesn't reply to E-mails. Its leaving a lot of people quite angry, feeling like the issues they bring up aren't important.
As a teacher, this policy is very frustrating. I can't leave my classroom for extended periods of the day, so office visits aren't an easy thing. Plus the telephone is a no-no for most topics, as students do listen in, quite a lot of E-mails I sent contained information that cannot be sent other ways. Sending text messages via private phones opens teachers up to some serious legal consequences--not to mention, its not permitted for us to use phones during the workday!
First, is there any legitimately good reason a boss would choose just to never reply to any E-mail from staff and instead request everything done in-person? Its obvious to me she knows how to use E-mail, we're required to use it for day-to-day things, we don't have some alternative messaging service setup.
Second, how can I convince her to change this policy, or what can I do to work around it?

Have you considered, you know, asking your principal?

“She even recently said she wasn't happy I didn't go to her about an issue, which was in an ignored E-mail.” - Did you tell her that you sent an email about the issue? Now that you know she doesn’t reply to emails. You will have to go to her in person to inform her of issues. In order to understand, why this individual does not reply to emails, you’ll have to ask them.

It isn't just 'reply' - it seems to be 'read'. I'd check with some competent authority on what the requirements are for notification of the principle about safety or other issues that require reporting. Then follow those requirements.

You will not get a satisfying answer here, you will have to talk to this person and ask them.

This question reminded me of Bel Kaufman's epistolary novel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_the_Down_Staircase .l, but that was before e-mail.

This ridiculous. In the business world this person would be fired in a week.
Your job is to be in the class with the kids obviously. If the principal won't put a protocol in place to address issues in the school, make the their bosses know without disrupting your day.
Start CC'ing people up the food chain. Even up to Superintendent and school board members if needed.
On the email subject lines append  "Request #2"   "Request #3"
If my kids went to this school I would be p*ssed.

That is a very bizarre policy to have. There could be a legitimate and beneficial reason for it, but I certainly can't think of one. And I don't think this would in any way be legally protective for her, especially since it is apparently an undocumented policy. I mean if you wrote an email to her confessing to a crime and she used this excuse to prove plausible deniability, then... sure.Now I'm not going to tell you not to transfer, but it seems like a drastic step. Have you talked to the principal about how she prefers you to contact her? Have you talked to other teachers about how they ask her questions? There's a lot you can do beyond She doesn't want me to email her so I can't do my job, oh well.

Trying to guess why the principal dislikes email is somewhat pointless. Some people just aren't comfortable with email. Trying to guess their reasons won't help. Asking them might.
But the right answer is to resort to older approaches. Paper notes. Phone calls. Appointments and/or trying to catch them when they have time to chat. If they have an executive assistant, you may be able to email the EA and ask them to ask the boss for you
You can't change the boss. You can change your own practices to work with them, assuming you want to work with them.
Or you can get a job where you are working with someone else.
